Conhost.exe with headless argument 100% CPU
On my production server, the CPU usage goes to 100% after every 10 days. Sometimes within 5 days too.
In task Manager, there are 2 instaces of conhost.exe everytime eating 50 - 50% of cpu each. I researched but only found information about "What is conhost". Someone suggested to check which command initiated the instance by adding command column in Task Manager. I did that and found below command:
conhost.exe --headless --inheritcursor --width 80 --height 30 --signal 0x328 --server 0x320

Here's screenshot:

I tried searching for those arguments separately, but no luck.
The only thing server has other that IIS runnning are 2 task schedules. Both are python scripts, one to take back up of database everyday and other to check an excel sheet.
If I run those tasks mannually, it starts the instance of conhost but that instance disappears after successful execution. Also, for those, the Command is just name of batch file and those are identified easily.

What is the parent of that conhost process (and what is the parent process of that)? Download Sysinternals ProcExp and check.

@grawity_u1686 I was using Process Monitor but didn't get anything. Now I also tried Process Explorer but no luck. It shows it as individual process. No parent or child process
